# sort out the block of data using vba macros if condition is met

Tags: vba, excel

As in the attached screenshot, i would like to sort out the block of data automatically using vba macros.

1. Example "Main"
2. repeats same thing for next block data i.e when there is empty cell  on "B:F"
3. data has to go in next respective sheet.

this is my current code

```
Sub Sortout()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Sheets(1).Activate
    n = Range("B:B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count
    'MsgBox n

    m = Range("C:C").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count
    'MsgBox m

    o = Range("D:D").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count
    'MsgBox o

    p = Range("E:E").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count
    'MsgBox p

    q = Range("F:F").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count
    'MsgBox q

    If (n = m) And (o = p) And (p = n) Then
        sunday = True
        MsgBox "B:F cells are blank"
    Else
        MsgBox "B:F cells are not blank"
        sunday = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Can anyone please help me out on this?

[image: DATA]

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Can you share your code and some details on where you specifically get stuck?

Comment: Thanks for quick response Sir. Yes, i have started with checking small condition that if all cells in same row "B:F" cells are empty or not. It would be grateful to help me on this to move further

Comment: @LokanathK, I moved code from your last comment into question. please delete your last comment

Answer (score 0):

**edited** to correct a range reference (added `.cell` right after `.Range(`)

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sortout()
    Dim cell As Range

    With Sheets(1) 'reference relevant sheet
        For Each cell In .Range("B1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) ' loop through its column B blank cells in range from row 1 down to last not empty one
            Sheets.Add.Name = cell.Offset(, -1) ' add a news sheet and name it after value in column A current cell row
            .Range(cell.Offset(1), cell.End(xlDown).End(xlDown)).Resize(, 5).Copy Sheets(cell.Offset(, -1).Value).Range("A1") ' copy values from range starting one cell below current one and ending 4 column left and one cell above next blank one in the same column 
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

of course there you need to add necessary checks for assure error handling (e.g.: target sheet already existent, ...) of which you may find dozens of examples around here

Comment: Thank you so much sir. i have tried your code. It is getting error as "Run time error '438'. Object doesn't support this property or method. However, the tabs are creating.. in the next sheet.

Comment: @LokanathK, sorry for the missing `cell`. see edited code

Comment: Thanks for correcting and its working now. yes, i will add necessary error handling code into it.

Answer (score 0):

try below:

```
k = Range("B2:F9").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count   
if k=40 then
With Sheets(2)
lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lRow1 = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 4
End With
Sheets(2).Range("A" & lRow  & ":I" & lRow1) = Sheets(1).Range("C4:K9").Value
end if
```

Above is for "Main". repeat and replace cell range for "Juice" and "popcorn"